# Saxon API (saxon9HE) output is not generating proper xml

Tags: c#, xslt, saxon

I am using below code for xsl transform.

```
var processor = new Processor();


XsltCompiler xslComp = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            XsltExecutable xslExec = xslComp.Compile(xslUri);
            XsltTransformer xslTrans = xslExec.Load();
            XdmDestination xdmD = new XdmDestination();
            Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();

            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(xmlPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                xslTrans.SetInputStream(fs, schemaUri); // set baseUri
                xslTrans.Run(xdmD);
            }

            XdmNode value = null;

            if (xdmD != null)
            {
                value = xdmD.XdmNode;
            }
```

Here is sample input xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;?xml',substring-after(//root/text(),'&lt;?xml'))" disable-output-escaping="yes"
/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input xml:

```
<root>
<![CDATA[

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:vms">
<nf:data>
  <show>
   <svs>
    <connections>
        <conn-name>qa-gdc1</conn-name>        
    </connections>
   </svs>
  </show>
</nf:data>
</nf:rpc-reply>

]]>
</root>
```

Output:

```
&lt?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?&gt
&ltnf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:vms"&gt
&ltnf:data&gt
  &ltshow&gt
   &ltsvs&gt
    &ltconnections&gt
        &ltconn-name&gt;qa-gdc1&lt;/conn-name&gt      
    &lt/connections&gt
   &lt/svs&gt
  &lt/show&gt
&lt/nf:data&gt
&lt/nf:rpc-reply&gt
```

Comment: Which version of Saxon HE is that? With 9.7 you could use the XPath 3 `parse-xml` to parse the embedded XML, then it also makes sense to expect an `XdmNode` as the result. If you want to rely on disable-output-escaping then I think you need to make sure the result is first serialized.

Answer (score 2):

(As I already explained in private email)

disable-output-escaping is an instruction to the serializer. It therefore has no effect if the result tree is not serialized. (You are creating a serializer, but you are not using it as the destination for the transformation.)